# Using ternary operator in JavaScript to invoke two functions

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Can this be done in JavaScript?

```
type == 1 ? function1() : function2();
```

Comment: Have you tested it? :)

Comment: you realize you can type javascript into the address bar of your browser to test it?

Comment: Try it yourself. Paste this: `javascript:void(true ? alert('t') : alert('f'))`

Comment: I'm just looking back at this question after all these years and it seem's pretty dumb that I didn't test it out on the console before posting it here. I think I was intimidated by the console back then.

Comment: Question from the title, solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements

Comment: @Swamyg - It is easy to test a piece of code, but the fact that it works  doesn't answer if it is good practice. Would you use it if it works, but gets hammered down by experienced JavaScript coders?  ;-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, that's valid code. It will invoke *either* `function1()` *or* `function2()`, but not both - depending on the value of `type`.

Comment: +1 It must be a slow day on SO when Jon Skeet and Ned Batchelder are answering JavaScript questions! :)

Comment: Got to hit that rep-cap, whatever it takes :D

Comment: It's valid, but JSHint will give a [warning](http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call) when ternary operators are used in this manner. To disable the warning you should set `expr: true` in your .jshintrc file.

Answer (score 7):

It won't invoke two functions.  It will invoke one of your two functions.