# Ternary operator with multiple operations

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Can I use a ternary operator when I have more than one operation to perform per case?

For example can I use it here?:

```
    if (dwelling) {
        dwelling = dwelling[0].nodeValue;      //first operation
        letterDwelling = dwelling[0].toUpperCase(); //second operation
 } else {
        dwelling = "";
        letterDwelling = "";
}
```

I've only used this syntax which allows one subsequent operation:

```
dwelling = dwelling ? dwelling[0].nodeValue : "";
```

Comment: You can specify multiple statements, comma separated: [see here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i highly advice against it for the sake of readability and extensibility you could:

```
dwelling ? (dwelling = dwelling[0].nodeValue, letterDwelling=dwelling[0].toUpperCase()) : (dwelling = letterDwelling = "");
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the side effects using the comma-notation you could use self-invoking functions instead which can handle your code:

```
(foo == bar) ? doSomething() : (function(){
    // here you can write all your code
    // and even return something useful
})();
```

Comment: Is the side effect you are talking about where the last value in the comma-notation is the value that is assigned? Quoted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Description)  "...the last comma-separated value of the parenthesis will be the value to be assigned". I cannot find any other adverse side effects. Although I do like this answer and think it is much prettier and easier to use than the current solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var dwelling = true;
(dwelling) ? (
    dwelling = 'a',      //first operation
    letterDwelling = 'a' //second operation
) : (
    dwelling = 'b',
    letterDwelling = 'b'
);
alert(dwelling);
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dipser/vpr0xmua/)