# Multiple operations in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, ternary-operator

Is it possible to have multiple operations within a ternary operator's if/else?

I've come up with an example below, probably not the best example but I hope you get what I mean.

```
var totalCount = 0;
var oddCount = 0;
var evenCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
    evenCount ++;
    totalCount ++;
  } else {
    oddCount ++;
    totalCount ++;
  }
}
```

into something like:

```
var totalCount = 0;
var oddCount = 0;
var evenCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] % 2 === 0? evenCount ++ totalCount ++ : oddCount ++ totalCount ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements

Comment: If you need to confuse other programmers, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to execute multiple expressions in place of a single expression:

```
arr[i] % 2 === 0? (evenCount++, totalCount++) : (oddCount++, totalCount++);
```

The result of the comma operator is the result of the last expression.

But yeah, don't use the conditional operator for side effects.