# Why does my code thinks that 60 is bigger than 135?

Tags: javascript

> i want to get the bigger number and subtract by the smaller number (input's value) even tho they are in the wrong order when you put them into the input like -1 = inputX / 1 = inputY then 1 = greater and -1 smaller, it works with other numbers, but these kinda break it idk why tho what did I do wrong?
>   [why does it think 60 is bigger than 135? look at the img...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGs4O.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x;
var y;
var big;
var small;
var result;
function calcT() {
    x = document.getElementById("inputX").value;
    y = document.getElementById("inputY").value;
    //result = x - y;
    if(x > y) {
      big = x;
      small = y;
       } else if(x < y) {
      big = y;
      small = x;
       }
    result = parseInt(big) - parseInt(small);
    document.getElementById("resultHere").innerHTML = result;

}
```

Comment: i thought i did tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please parse to integer your inputX and inputY before comparing.

It is treating inputX and inputY as string.

so '135' > '65' is false &&
'65' > '135' is true.

```
 var x; var y; var big; var small; var result;
function calcT() { 
 x = document.getElementById("inputX").value; 
 y = document.getElementById("inputY").value; //result = x - y; 
 x= parseInt(x); // Missing point <--
 y= parseInt(y); // Missing point <--
 if(x > y) { big = x; small = y; 
 } else if(x < y) { 
 big = y; small = x; } 
 result = big - small;
 document.getElementById("resultHere").innerHTML = result;
```

}

Comment: oh, that makes sense... my bad :p

Comment: nvm i just find out >~<

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to do this:

```
var result = Math.abs(x-y);
```

This will save you the trouble of using the if-else ladder and basically give you the same thing in 1 line.

And the issue is with you comparing strings instead of numbers as pointed out by others. You could do something like:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputX").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputY").value);
var result = (x<y) ? y-x : x-y;
```

Comment: but if u put in a diferent order when you are subtracting the value is diferent

Comment: Idk i'm kinda dumb most of the times, i was trying to Make something all in my own without looking at anything to test what i could do, so i'm not that efficient and stuff

Comment: are you expecting negative numbers?

Comment: not really, i'm just kinda being lazy with this code i'm just trying to get something to work, and it requires i subtract the greater value by the smaller one

Comment: is it an issue to have if-else ladders?... i mean is it that bad? its just a tiny test i did to make something tho

Comment: Well not really, except when both numbers are equal since you used else-if and not else.
Ternary looks cleaner in this case, easier to understand, less LOC, no need for additional variables. It's a matter of personal preference in the end. Either won't make much difference.

Comment: i just wanted the code to actually work, thats all i really needed so i guess i'm fine xD

Comment: As you wish. But isn't it giving you NaN when both inputs are same right now?

Comment: it is, i addeded another else if for when x == y and now its fine xD

Comment: Lol. Now do you see why the ternary was a better choice in this case? 10 lines of code brought down to 1. 
You might want to update the accepted answer now. :p

Comment: idk how the code u suggested works tho it gives the same output?

Comment: like...? result = (x less than y) ? y minus x : x minus y?

Comment: It should. Let me explain how a ternary works in short:
var result = (condition) ? (value returned if condition is true) : (value returned if condition is false);
It's that simple. :)

Comment: Yeah. Try it. You just might like it.

Comment: if it works i may use it but... it looks hard to memorize that pattern tho xD looks kinda strange to look at u know

Comment: i think it works, but i can't tell, the x and y are undefined if i console log them but it gives the result, idk whats happening lool

Comment: You can't console log inside the ternary. You can log the result though.

Comment: that i know, it shows me the result, but i guess if it works its ok, maan i got so focused in my code i forgot to drink my coffee now its cold </3

Comment: @BloooDoopy : Don't Worry, its very simple.
**Syntax** : _condition ? expr1 : expr2_  
Whatever you wrote within _if(**condition**)_ followed by a _?_ **then condition** _:_ **else condition statement** 

you can also use console.log in a ternary operator. 

**(1>2)?console.log('1>2'):console.log('1<2');**

[use multiple commands in ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the values directly - this results in comparing the text '135' with the text '60'. Show should instead compare the integer values of your inputs - e. g. convert the inputs to number before the if statement using parseInt(...).

Comment: i wonder how did i not see that, i WAS changing this code for like 30 minutes trying to make it get the Number not the string, but i didn't know how to  so after 30 minutes i just gave up and came here ask omg now i feel so dumb >~<

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two strings.  You need to parse them to ints before you do the comparison:

```js
console.log('as strings...', '123' > '50')
console.log('as numbers...', Number('123') > Number('50'))
```

Comment: I WAS THINKING IT WAS DOING THAT BUT I DIDN'T KNOW HOW OR WHERE OR omg

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with variables define. Try to move `var x,y,big,small;` into the function.