# Why ternary operator in JS with multiple statements is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I know ternary operator with multiple statements works in React/JavaScript with:

`condition ? (statement1,statement2,...) : (statement);`.

[Explored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements#) to get to know how it works.

Following is my code which is causing an error:

```
localProducts[productFoundAt].qty > 0 ? (localProducts[productFoundAt].qty-- , localCartedProducts[iterator].qty++) : alert("More quantity not available");
```

Error:

> ./src/reducers/reducer.js
>     Line 26:21:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Similar code with `if/else` is working fine:

```
if (localProducts[productFoundAt].qty > 0) {
    localProducts[productFoundAt].qty--;
    localCartedProducts[iterator].qty++
} else {
    alert("More quantity not available");
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? Thanks for the help. 
Also why similar code working here?

```js
let a = 10;
let b = 10;

a==b ? (a-- , b--):alert("Hello World");
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Those operands of the comma operator are expressions, not statements.

Comment: The error looks like it's coming from ESLint, not JavaScript.

Comment: Your linter is complaining because you shouldn't use the conditional operator when you don't need an expression as the result anywhere. Just write proper readable code, using the `if` statement!

Comment: Ternary operator is intended to be used with single expression, but you still want to use it in multi-expression, that is not even valid JS at all

Comment: @Justinas It is *valid*, it is just an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Justinas, please make sure you read my question thoroughly with complete details. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bergi, Please refer to the question edits as counter to your 1st comment. Thanks

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen I'd argue that the other snippet should fail the linting as well.

Comment: @Bergi, I surrender, it's failing in linting but can you please elaborate why it's doing so when it's a valid JS statement?  

Or should I refer your 2nd comment as answer to this question?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen EsLint doesn't say it's not valid, it complains that it is bad style. That's exactly the job of a linter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a valid syntax. It is just an `es-lint` error which you can ignore by adding the following line:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
localProducts[productFoundAt].qty > 0 ? (localProducts[productFoundAt].qty-- , localCartedProducts[iterator].qty++) : alert("More quantity not available");
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's working fine. Can you please help me understanding the reason?

Comment: We just bypassed the rule of es-lint that was producing the warning.

Comment: I know why it worked, but I wanna know why it was not working given that it was a valid statement?

Comment: **It was working!** Lint rules are established to catch common areas of code that are easy to create baked in bugs, or lead to less readable code, or any other number of reasons. It is very opinionated. Somewhere in a lint config that rule is configured to be an error. You can modify it to only be a warning (so builds succeed), remove the rule all together, or keep it and add the disable override for those times when want to use a ternary like that.