# Change text on button depending on value of a number - React using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, buttonclick

I have a counter that is the index of my array, on every button click the next element is showing. What I want to achieve is I want a specific text to show on the beginning and when index becomes 0 again and a different text on the in between numbers.
Here is my code till now, the text stays the same but I am not sure what is wrong.

```
function App() {


const questions_size = Data.length; 
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const current = Data[num].content;

  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Παιξε");
  const change_text = (text) => setButtonText(text);

  const callTwoFunc = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
    setButtonText("Επομενο");
  }

  return (

  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>

          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {  num < questions_size - 1 ? callTwoFunc() : setNum(0); change_text("Παιξε"); }}>{buttonText}</Button>
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>

              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>

                <p style={{ fontFamily: 'Tangerine, serif', fontSize: '35px', textShadow: '4px 4px 4px #aaa' }}>{current}</p>
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>



  </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

For now it's only saying "Παιξε" but i want it become "Επόμενο" after my first click, and then when num becomes zero to become "Παίξε" again.

Comment: First of, you are calling `change_text("Παιξε");` in each click, so it will override all your changes. But in order to let us help you with this, you need to provide more details on your code (like what is `questions_size` value?) and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current attempt.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the questions_size variable but to more more accurate this is how many elements my json file has. Ok I will try to add some more data to be able for you to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `change_text('Παιξε');` part of your `onClick` function of the Button:

```
onClick={() => {
    num < questions_size - 1 ? callTwoFunc() : setNum(0);
    change_text('Παιξε');
  }}
```

It will always change the button to *Παιξε*. It is easier to move that logic into `callTwoFunc`:

```
const callTwoFunc = () => {
    setNum(prev => {
     if(prev < questions_size - 1) {
       return prev + 1;
     } else {
       return 0;
     }
   })
  }
```

And for the button as there are only two states, it is easier to do it directly instead of using state:

```
<Button>{num === 0 ? "Παιξε" : "Επομενο" }</Button>
```

Comment: This is such a clever answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const Data = [{content: ""},{content: ""}]
  const questions_size = Data.length; 
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  // const current = Data[num].content;

  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Παιξε");
  const change_text = (text) => setButtonText(text);

  const callTwoFunc = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
    change_text("Επομενο")
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('click',num < questions_size - 1);
    if(num < questions_size - 1){
      callTwoFunc()
    }
    else{
      console.log('ding');
      setNum(0);
      change_text("Παιξε");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>{buttonText}</button>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try doing like this...guess it will work

Answer (score 2):

As I said earlier **the actual part that ruined your code is calling `change_text("Παιξε");` in each click**, so **it will override all your change**, so the best practice to overcome such an issue is to make your `onClick` function more generic. So you have to pass all the logic to your `callTwoFunc()` function. One of the practices can be using traditional `if-else` in your function.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
const callTwoFunc = () => {
  if (num < questions_size - 1) {
    setNum(num + 1)
    change_text('Επομενο')
  } else {
    setNum(0)
    change_text('Παιξε')
  }
}

return (
  <Button
    variant='contained'
    color='primary'
    onClick={() => {
      callTwoFunc()
    }}
  >
    {buttonText}
  </Button>
)
```

**Working demo:**

I didn't know what is the actual `Data` is so I just mocked it with empty strings.

[image: CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 1):

By doing like so

```
num < questions_size - 1 ? callTwoFunc() : setNum(0); change_text("Παιξε");
```

the operator actually goes like `num < questions_size - 1 ? callTwoFunc() : setNum(0);` while after it and in any case `change_text("Παιξε");` will run. change the opertor to standart `if` syntax, for having a block to each case instead just one expression

---

```
       if (num < questions_size - 1) callTwoFunc()
       else { setNum(0); change_text("Παιξε"); }
```

---

or use comma operator - [Javascript - Ternary Operator with Multiple Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements)