# how do i execute multiple if/then in onClick ternary function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

trying to debug, and not sure if this structure works...

```
onClick={()=>{ //2. an image is clicked, and the choice is added to the choiceOrder state, and then a jsonupdate is called -- 3. in ChooseBy.js
   //onclick, add or remove the choice
   choosebyprops.setChoiceOrder( choiceOrder=>
                                    choiceOrder.includes(attrprops.attrChoice)
                                    ?
                                    (
                                    (choiceIndex = choiceOrder.findIndex(attrprops.attrChoice)),
                                    (choiceOrder.filter(list=> list!==attrprops.attrChoice)),
                                    (choosebyprops.setJsonList(jsonList=> jsonList.splice(choiceIndex) )) //removes the json data for that choice
                                    )
                                    :
                                    (
                                    ( [...choiceOrder,attrprops.attrChoice] ),
                                    (choosebyprops.setJsonList(jsonList=> [...jsonList, UpdateJson({...allprops})]))  //adds json data for that choice
                                    )
                                    )
}}
```

i'm basically trying to make a list of jsons, where if i click the button a filtered json is added to the list for that option, if i unclick it then it's removed.

but i just wanna know if i can have multiple statements inside that that ternary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to abuse the conditional operator as a replacement for `if`/`else` - `if`/`else` will allow you to create *blocks*, which statements can be put into much more naturally.

It sounds like you're looking to do something like this:

```
choosebyprops.setChoiceOrder(choiceOrder => {
    if (choiceOrder.includes(attrprops.attrChoice)) {
        const choiceIndex = choiceOrder.findIndex(attrprops.attrChoice);
        choosebyprops.setJsonList(jsonList => jsonList.splice(choiceIndex)); // this splice sounds wrong - don't mutate in React
        return choiceOrder.filter(list => list !== attrprops.attrChoice);
    } else {
        choosebyprops.setJsonList(jsonList => [...jsonList, UpdateJson({ ...allprops })]);
        return [...choiceOrder, attrprops.attrChoice];
    }
});
```

Comment: ahhh thanks. about the splice, should i do some sort of filter on the indexes?

Comment: There's no context as to what `choosebyprops` or `setJsonList` is in your code, how it's connected to `choiceOrder`, or what you're trying to do with that statement, so I can't really say.

Comment: If it's stateful, and you want to remove the element at that index from state (and the `choiceOrder` has the same index of the element to remove), then you probably want `setJsonList((_, i) => i !== choiceIndex)`

Comment: i will try that!, waiting on the 2 minutes to give you the answer check mark hah

Comment: it looks like theres one issue here and that's the last line, which kind of explains why i had it in ternary originally... basically the ```[...choiceOrder,attrprops.attrChoice];``` line needs to happen first in the ```else``` block, because the ```UpdateJson``` function uses the updated state.  would i need to do two if/then statements to make up for this you think?

Comment: You might have to use a `useEffect` callback, with the dependency array of what changes, but without more context of what the code is and what you're aiming for it's impossible to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more convenient to make a separate function for each handler and use the ternary operator to choose which function to be invoked. Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements) question for more explanation.

Comment: is that the case even with the if/then conversion?