# Convert if/else to conditional (ternary) operator

Tags: javascript, function, dom, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I´m new in JavaScript.
I´d like to convert the conditional If to a ternary operator, but I don´t know how.
I leave all the code below in case someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
  <img src="images/animal.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  <button onclick="change()" type="button">Change</button>

  <script>
    let estadoCambio = true;
    function change(){
     if (!estadoCambio){
      document.images[0].src="images/animal.jpg";
      estadoCambio = true;
     } else {
      document.images[0].src="images/flor.jpg";
      estadoCambio = false;
     }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I tried using expressions like:

- condition ? (()=>{expresion1; expresion2})() : (()=>{expresion3; expresion4})()
- condition ? [] : []

But no one works.

I am looking to change it by order of my programming teacher.

Comment: Why do you want that? It actively hurts the readability of your code.

Comment: Hmmm...[same topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6678411/2743458) but without the down-voting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Ternary Operator with Multiple Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678411/javascript-ternary-operator-with-multiple-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use destructuring to assign two variables in the conditional expression.

```
[document.images[0].src, estadoCambio] = estadoCambio ? 
    ["images/flor.jpg", false] : 
    ["images/animal.jpg", true];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your teacher probably was looking for:

```js
document.images[0].src = `images/${estadoCambio ? 'flor' : 'animal'}.jpg`;
estadoCambio = !estadoCambio;
```