# When checkbox is checked show message in javascript

Tags: asp.net

I want like this in javascript,when checkbox is visible show message1 else show message2.

Comment: you mean when checkbox is check show message one and when unchecked show message 2

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched? Did you read the FAQ? [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: don't ask any question on getting ready made code without trying code, because stack-overflow is only for problems and solutions not for ready made code.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type='checkbox' onchange='handleChange(this);'>Checkbox</label>
```

**JS:**

```
function handleChange(cb) {
  if(cb.checked == true){
   alert('Message 1');
  }else{
   alert('Message 2');
  }
}
```

**JSBIN:**
 **http://jsbin.com/abukor/2**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
checkBox.onchange = function () {
    console.log("Checked:" + checkBox.checked)
};
```

Comment: The requirement was `when checkbox is visible show message1 else show message2`. This answer neither shows `message1` nor `message2`. This answer is "wrong".

Comment: @Pang I think the reader can figure out the `if` on their own... `checkBox.checked` is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){
    alert("message1");
}else{
    alert("message1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript ternary operator

```
var msg = ($("#MyCheckbox").is(":checked")) ? 'message1' : 'message2';
alert(msg);
```

You could of course in-line the ternary to make it really compact

Also checkout this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323946/96505) for some other examples of using the ternary operator.

If you want to show the message if the checkbox itself is visible then you can use the [:visible operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/96505) which would make the code:

```
var msg = ($("#MyCheckbox").is(":visible")) ? 'message1' : 'message2';
alert(msg);
```