# Can the value of JavaScript's "if" statement be used?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, expression

If you enter the following into Firefox's Browser Console, the result is `456`:

```
if (false) { 123; } else if (true) { 456; } else { 789; }
```

If you adjust the `true`/`false` combinations, you can also get `123` or `789` as a result.  However, if you try and do something like:

```
var a = if (false) { 123; } else if (true) { 456; } else { 789; };
```

you just get a syntax error.  The syntax error doesn't surprise me, but I'm wondering what the point is of `if` statements having a value if that value can't be used.

So my question is: can an `if` statement be used as an expression, and if so, how?

---

EDIT: Thanks for the responses so far, but just to be absolutely clear, I know I could use functions and/or the ternary operator to achieve what I've described, but I specifically want to know whether the 'return value' of an `if` statement can be used, i.e. whether an `if` statement can be used as an expression.  I'm **not** asking for alternative ways of setting a value based upon various conditions.

(And if an `if` cannot be used as an expression, then why does Firefox's Browser Console show a value for the first example above?)

Comment: the else part is unreachable in your second case

Comment: Yeah, I realise that thanks - these are just examples!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operators:

```
var a = false ? 123 : true ? 456 : 789;
```

Comment: Thanks, I would usually use the ternary operator, but my question is specifically about the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

have as a function instead:

```
function a(b) //where b is your boolean
{
   if(b)
   {
      return 123;
   }
   else
   {
      return 456;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator: var x = (true ? 432 : 765); // will set x to 432

See also [JavaScript ternary operator example with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Use function instead of directly using that expression. And then you also have to return those values.

```
 
var a=function(){if (false) { return 123; } else if (true) { return 456; } else { return 789; }}
alert(a());
```