# javascript syntax for ? and :

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:

**1.** I have a JavaScript function code:

```
var firstOrNull = function (elems){
    return (elems.length > 0 ) ? elems[0] : null;
}
```

What does `?` and `:` means in this code?

**2.** What is the meaning of this code:

```
var stopEvent = function(event){ event.stopPropagation() }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions

Comment: what about stoppropogation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is [`Conditional Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
2. `stopPropagation` method of javascript event. It [uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) to prevent further propagation of the current event.

Answer (score 0):

`? and :` pair indicate ternary operator in Javascript.

`(elems.length > 0 ) ? elems[0] : null;` line means if `elems length` is greater than `zero` then return `elems[0]` otherwise return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the **ternary operators**

```
if(elements.length > 0){
   return elems[0];
} else {
return  null;
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
return (elems.length > 0 ) ? elems[0] : null;
```

[ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#JavaScript)