# Jquery: Combine multiple user inputs into one text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put together multiple user inputs and then combine them into one textarea after button click.

For example: 
User1:Hey, I just met you
User2:And this is crazy
User3:But Here's my number so call me maybe

Combined Result:
Hey, I just met you, And this is crazy, But Here's my number so call me maybe

Here's my code the button click is currently not working but when I tried it before it did work so I was thinking I have some problem w/ my Jquery that triggers this unusual result:

HTML and Imports:

```
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <input class="combine" id="input1" disabled="true"></input>
      <input class="combine" id="input2" disabled="true"></input>
      <input class="combine" id="input3" disabled="true"></input>
      <input class="combine" id="input4" disabled="true"></input>
      <input class="combine" id="input5" disabled="true"></input>
      <input class="combine" id="input6" disabled="true"></input>

      <input class="combine" id="Voltes5" disabled="true" size="45"></input>


      <button id="setVal">Set</button>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#setVal').on('click',function(){

        jQuery(function(){
    var form = $('.combine');
    form.each(function(){
    $('.Voltes5').append($(this).text()+ ' ');
    });
    });
        });
        });
```

Update for sir Arun P Johny

User1: If theres a (no comma when combined)
User2: will
User3: there's a way

Combined Result:
If theres a will, there's a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        var form = $('.combine').not('#Voltes5');
        var vals = form.map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            return value ? value : undefined;
        }).get();
        $('#Voltes5').val(vals.join(', '))
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hztMj/)

Comment: sir I appreciate your answer and it did solve my problem but I just can't accept it without undestanding it, can I ask what happenened in this line return value ? value : undefined; ? again thank you

Comment: @user3046019 ? is a ternary operator, it reads like an if else statement. that statement could also read like this - `if(value) { return value } else { return undefined };` if there was a value return it else return undefined. here is a question relating to the ternary operator -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions

Comment: @user3046019 that is a ternary operator... if an input element is blank then we dont want to add the empty value to the `vals` array so we returns undefined

Comment: sir can I ask If I can make a condition in which the first user input does not have a comma (,) when combined and the rest will have them? I'm sorry fo this added question I was just hoping to finish it thank you

Comment: @user3046019 sorry can you explain the requirement again.. if possible with a sample

Comment: sir @Arun P Johny I posted my question is it possible to add that condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#setVal').on('click',function(){
    var val='';
    $('.combine').not('#Voltes5').each(function(){
        val+=$(this).val();
    });
    $('#Voltes5').val(val);
  });
});
```

.text() will give text of the element ,for input val u have to use .val()

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this:

```
$('#setVal').on('click', function () {
    $(".combine[id^=input]").each(function () {
        if(this.value) {
            $("#Voltes5")[0].value += ' ' + this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this..

I'd do it this way using an array:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setVal').on('click', function () {
        //create an array for the values
        var inpAry = [];

        $('.combine').each(function () {
            //add each value to the array
            inpAry.push($(this).val+' ');
        });
        //set the final input val 
        $('#Voltes5').val(inpAry);
    });
});
```

but you would need to remove the `combine` class from `#setVal` because that would be included in the `.each`.

This way it would also be possible to have the final box updated on `keyup` as I'm not just appending the values, the combined values are set each time.

Comment: No discussion of why this is a better approach, or why OP should remove the combine class

Comment: I'd hope that actually reading the commented code would be enough @unwitting you should take a look at when and why down voting should be used... I'd not say my answer meets that criteria.

Comment: I don't think so - there was no comment in the code about the combine class, your edit is much more informative

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner for non-readability ;)

```
$('#setVal').click(function(){$('#Voltes5').val($('.combine').not('#Voltes5').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(''))});
```

Expanded:

```
$('#setVal').click(function(){
$('#Voltes5').val(
  $('.combine')
  .not('#Voltes5')
  .map(
    function(){
      return $(this).val();
    })
  .get()
  .join('')
);
});
```

Get fiddly with it: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/u57Zp/

Answer (score 0):

So there's immediate big problem in the code, which is that you're referring to your `Voltes5` element as a class, not an ID. The jQuery selector you want is:

```
#Voltes5
```

instead of:

```
.Voltes5
```

There are a few other things to think about too, though, for the sake of functionality and best practices. Firstly, the `Voltes5` element also has class `combine`, meaning that the `$('.combine').each()` call will *include* this element. The outcome of this is that it will also append its current text to itself when the code is run (or, when the code is run with the above correction).

When grabbing the current entered text of an input element, a jQuery `.val()` call is what you want, not `.text()` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text) for some more discussion.

Another thing that could be noted is that you should really explicitly specify what *sort* of `input` these elements are; `<input type="text">` is hugely preferable to `<input>`.

Finally, `input` is a *void element* ([reading](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/)), meaning it shouldn't have any content between opening and closing tags. Ideally, you wouldn't even give a closing tag; either have just the opening tag, or *self-close* it:

```
<input>
<input />
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

replace `$('.Voltes5').append($(this).text()+ ' ');`

with

```
$('#Voltes5').append($(this).text()+ ' ');
```

Comment: I did sir but it didn't work, I'm tweaking a few things I'll update the question if get more info