# parameters in this function call are not understood

Tags: java, javascript

This function is supposed to take two parameters, however there are characters included that I do not understand what they mean. What is the value of "?". What are the two parameters in this function, I know panel.id is one of them . any link to a library that explain them well ? thank you

```
setPanelType(panel.id, ((encType) ? PANEL_ST_ENC : PANEL_NORMAL))
```

The duplicate question posted here might be explaining what the "?" operator is. However I was not sure if it is used differently in a function parameter call. This question is not a duplicate of any.

Comment: `... ? ... : ...` is called the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I assume this code is in Java, or in JavaScript. It would be best to only tag the language it's actually in. (Java != JavaScript)

Comment: Side note: All of the parentheses in that code other than the outermost ones are completely unnecessary (Java or JavaScript, or just about any other language syntactically derived from B). E.g., `setPanelType(panel.id, encType ? PANEL_ST_ENC : PANEL_NORMAL)` would be fine.

Comment: The project I am working on has both javascript and java code implemented. I to be honest was not sure this code lands to which language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run in to something called the "[conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)"*. It's basically a short way of writing an if-statement.

For example:

```
String var;
var = 1 > 0 ? "It's bigger than 0" : "It's 0 or smaller";
```

Is the same as:

```
String var;
if(1 > 0){
    var = "It's bigger than 0";
}else{
    var = "It's 0 or smaller";
}
```

---

* It's also sometimes called the "ternary" operator, but that's not quite correct. It's ***a*** "ternary operator" (an operator that accepts three operands, just like the multiplication operator `*` is a *binary* operator because it accepts *two* operands), but in theory there could be others. In fact, I think it's the only ternary operator in Java or JavaScript (at least for now).

Comment: Kudo's to T.J. Crowder for addition(s).

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is shorthand for a conditional action in Javascript.

(condition) ? (true action) : (false action)

Related: [JavaScript ternary operator example with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions)

Comment: Replace "action" with "expression".

Answer (score 0):

The '?' means Ternary Operator as said above,  encType is a boolean variable.

```
setPanelType(panel.id, ((encType) ? PANEL_ST_ENC : PANEL_NORMAL))
```

is equals to:

```
if (encType)
   setPanelType(panel.id, PANEL_ST_ENC))
else 
  setPanelType(panel.id, PANEL_NORMAL))
```