# What does the ? symbol do in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

For example, this code snippet:

```
var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
```

What does the ? do?

Update for anyone searching: 
This link provides a good explanation with examples

[JavaScript ternary operator example with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions)

Comment: That's a ternary operator, not related to jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Exactly the same thing it does in JavaScript or any other C-descendant language.

Comment: FYI, because jQuery event is normalized, you could simplify it to: `var key = e.which || 0;`

Comment: This is a more useful and explanatory link with examples than the duplicate one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions