# ternary calling functions in ajax call

Tags: javascript

//UPDATE: nevermind I'm dumb. It works, but I'll change it to if/else

I have an ajax function and on success it'll update some css styles. If valueExists is true, I'd like to add multiple css styles and I place these css styles in a function

```
.success(function(data) {
    data.valueExists ? multipleChanges($("#element")) : $("#element").addClass("classStyleTwo");      
});

//Outside of success function multiple css changes
function multipleChanges(element){
        $(element).addClass("classStyleTwo");
        $(element).css({color: "#1abc9c"});
}
```

The problem is that the ternary is in an async request, so the function multipleChanges is called instantly. I'm still a bit rusty on callback functions I tried placing multipleChanges inside another  function like...

```
function wrapper (cb, element){
   return cb(element);
}

.success(function(data) {
    data.valueExists ? wrapper(multipleChanges, $("#element")) : $("#element").addClass("classStyleTwo");      
});
```

Comment: As a side note, ternaries are mostly used to assign a value to a variable, not to perform operations

Comment: yeah I have multiple ternaries so I tried avoiding the if/else style. I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions, but you're right

Comment: use ternaries where it makes more sense (to avoid duplicating assignment expressions). A ternary isn't by default better than `if else`.

Comment: Why ever you needed a hard to read code over easier to debug one? Think when yours get sized and found all the scripts are one lined :( I'm referring to "I have multiple ternaries" anyways