# Explaining a portion of JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

Can any body explain this portion `(url ? "/" + url : "")` in the following function:

```
 function sendAjaxRequest(httpMethod, callback, url) {
 $.ajax("/api/web" + (url ? "/" + url : ""), {
 type: httpMethod, success: callback
 });
 }
```

as I cann't understand how it interpreted by calling wrapper function and get the intended URL value,

Comment: This is a ternary operator: `a ? b : c` which reads if `a` is true, then return `b` otherwise `c`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript ternary operator example with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res = "/api/web" + (url ? "/" + url : ""` is equal to the following:

```
if (url) // if url is not empty
{
    res =  "/api/web" + "/" + url;
}
else 
{
    res =  "/api/web" + ""
}
```